# Create Cookie OnSubmit Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, cookies

I need to know how to create a cookie on submit from a form.

I have a page that shows a modal window from colorbox when you visit it. Inside the modal is a form for a newsletter email signup. If the user clicks off the form or cancels the cookies should only expire for 1 day. If the user submits their email on the form the cookie should expire for 1 year. So basically i need the form to overwrite the cookie if submitted. and here is what i have so far for code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../cb/colorbox.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../cb/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function showModal() {
  $.colorbox({href:"content.php", open: true,iframe: true,width:"400px", height:"200px"});
}

var visited = readCookie('mypopup');

if (!visited) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    showModal();
    createCookie('mypopup','no',0);
  });
}

//]]>
</script>
```

So need the onSubmit cookie code so i can place that on my "content.php" page so it overwrites this existing cookie when submitted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure you can do that, if the form is in an iframe. you could always have the form submission push the new cookie (use the "Set-Cookie" header from the php code).

if the form is in the same page,

```
<form id='simpleform'>
....
</form>
```

then you'd use jquery to capture

```
$('#simpleform').submit(function(e) {
    createCookie('mypopup', 'no', 365);
});
```

but it seems like what you'd want is for your php form code to evaluate the form and only set the cookie if the user submitted a valid form. [/2-cents]

Comment: i just want it so if a user submits the form they wont see the pop up for a year, and if  they dont submit the form then the should see the pop up 1 per day

Comment: so should i remove that cookie code off of the page and only have it on the submit?

Comment: that's what i would do. that way you can verify the email address is valid (with standard checks), and a clever user with a javascript console couldn't just call your function.

Comment: i dont think that would work, So should it place a cookie if they submit and place another cookie if they dont submit?

Comment: when the user hits your site, you could check to see if they present you with a cookie you left on their computer. if they don't, put a cookie down that's valid for one day. if they do, then don't put down a new cookie (unless you want to store more/different information). from the javascript, you would then read that cookie and offer the popup if the cookie had expired. then if they submit something valid, give them a new cookie, valid for a year.